# Show $(1,1)$ tensor acts as a map from vectors to vectors

Tags: tensor-calculus

In Sean Carroll's Spacetime and Geometry book, pg. 22, it was stated that a (1,1) tensor acts as a map from vectors to vectors:
$${T^\mu}_\nu: V^\nu\rightarrow {T^\mu}_\nu V^\nu.$$

I tried showing this myself by considering the action of the $(1,1)$ tensor $T$ on a vector $V$:
$$T(0,V)={T^\mu}_\nu e_\mu\otimes e^\nu(0,V),$$
where $e_\mu$ and $e^\nu$ are the basis vectors for the vector space and the dual vector space respectively.

I then proceed on to get
$$\begin{equation}
T(0,V)={T^\mu}_\nu e_\mu(0)\times e^\nu(V) \\={T^\mu}_\nu e_\mu(0)\times e^\nu(V^\rho e_\rho)\\={T^\mu}_\nu e_\mu(0)\times V^\rho e^\nu( e_\rho)\\={T^\mu}_\nu e_\mu(0)\times V^\rho \delta^\nu_\rho\\={T^\mu}_\nu \times0\times V^\nu\\=0
\end{equation}$$
where I used $e_\mu(e^\rho)=\delta^\rho_\mu$ so $e_\mu(0)=0$.

The result is clearly not corret. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps this might be better suited for maths SE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $(1,1)$ tensor is a multilinear map from $V^* \times V$ to the underlying field of scalars of V, which is typically $\mathbb{R}$. In you example, your first element in $(0, V)$ is $0 \in V^*$, and since the tensor is a linear map on $V^*$ it will always map $(0,v)$ to $0$ for any $v \in V$.

You can also think of a $(1,1)$ tensor $T$ as a linear map $T:V \rightarrow V$. If $T$ has components ${T^\mu}_\nu$ relative to a given basis and $V$ has compoonents $v^{\nu}$ relative to the same basis then the components of the vector $T(V)$ are $(T(V))^\mu = {T^\mu}_\nu v^{\nu}$.